# Amount of subsets if the elements must be contiguous

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have looked for this question but I haven't seen an answer anywhere. My question is if we have a set of size n and we have to choose k elements from the set, then we would have n c k possible subsets.

But what if we only wanted subsets that are contiguous in the set? I am sorry if it is poorly worded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sets on their own don't have any sense of 'contiguous', they need to be partially or fully ordered sets in order to have this work. The question is, is your set partially ordered, or fully ordered? What are the elements of the set? Is it just the natural numbers from 1 to n, listed in order?

Comment: If your set is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and you want subsets of $4$ successive terms then the possibilities are $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{2,3,4,5\}$.  Try some other cases and the pattern should become obvious

Comment: What have you tried? e. g. What kind of properties do you observe for the sets in your description have?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, to obtain $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.